# Mysql Count query optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have the below query to optimize.

```
SELECT count(*) AS count FROM area 
INNER JOIN entity ON area.id = entity.id
INNER JOIN areacust ON area.id = areacust.id 
WHERE entity.deleted=0 
AND area.id > 0
```

There are indexes on deleted, ids on all the tables.

Now when i have suppose 20 Lac (2 million) of records then the query takes lots of time to give me the result. Its between 10 to 20 seconds.

How can i optimize it more. Also is there any other technique to get count.

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  vtiger_crmentity    ref PRIMARY,entity_deleted_idx  entity_deleted_idx  4      const    729726  Using where; Using index
1   SIMPLE  area    eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   area.id 1   Using index
1   SIMPLE  areacust    eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   area.id 1   Using where; Using index
```

New explain for composite key

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  entity  ref PRIMARY,entity_deleted_idx,comp_index   deleted_idx 4   const   928304  Using index
1   SIMPLE  area    eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   entity.id   1   Using index
1   SIMPLE  areacust    eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   entity.idid 1   Using index
```

Comment: Post `EXPLAIN` plan of your query

Comment: have you tried adding FORCE INDEX ..... to the select?

Comment: how to adde force index in this query

Comment: `FROM area FORCE INDEX (area.id)`

Comment: @JohnRuddell, I am curious if replacing * with any valid column name will reduce some of execution time? like select count(id) instead of count(*), after all we just want a count, so instead of fetching all the columns calling only one..

Comment: query error right syntax use near .id after adding force index.

Comment: sorry i think its just (id)

Comment: @Pramod i tried that but did not work

Comment: @Pramod  theres a few things about that.. so first if you want to count everything most people will write it as `COUNT(*)`.. if you want to count only things in one table you could do `count(a.id)` or even `(a.*)`.. but that would only matter if there were `LEFT JOINS` that caused there to be additional rows... MySQL performs almost identically for `COUNT(ID)` or `COUNT(*)`.. except when there are `null` values to be counted... if there are null values you should ALWAYS use `COUNT(*)` because MySQL knows how to handle it better that way.. cuts the execution time in half.

Comment: @JohnRuddell no did not work using force index same time.

Comment: @JohnRuddell It's already using the primary for that table.

Comment: @RahulTailwal seel the documentation.. you need to call the index http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index-hints.html.. you can also force the index for joins... this would only ensure that its using the index.. may not speed it up if its already using it

Comment: @JohnRuddell I tried to do with different combination but dont think there is any solution for this. As i have already added index where needed.

Comment: It seems like your indexes aren't the ones you want.. You should try removing all of them.. And start with just one.. Do the pk and fk from the tables.. Do just one and Try joking and a e how long it takes.. Add another index and join the next table.. That should be a good stating point.

Comment: Also I'd recommend researching indexes and the best way to use them just so you know how to set it up.. Currently its using the entity.deleted index first which is wrong so that's why you should restart

Comment: @JohnRuddell For about 18 Lac records. explain show 8 lac lookups. What should be the lookups. can i do something with mysql server increasing some memory etc.

Comment: Please use metric system measurements when asking questions, even though you said what lack/lakh is - just use millions for measurement. Increase `innodb_buffer_pool` size if you haven't. Remove `deleted` index if you haven't, it's cardinality is too low to be an index (cardinality = possible values / number of records).

Answer (score 1):

As per comments, if you want to keep the query in question - you have to allocate more resources to your MySQL instance. I am assuming you use InnoDB for storage engine, otherwise this advice is useless:

Increase the value of `innodb_buffer_pool` variable. As much as you can. You want to allocate as much RAM as possible.

Also, get rid of index on `deleted` column, it's useless. Its cardinality is too low for it to be an index.

The other "technique" that you can (should) use is taking care of this count manually.

Create the table that holds the count number you are interested in. Every time you update / insert / delete the entity or area record - update the count value manually (increase, decrease).

That way all you have to do is look up a single record of a single table. Setting up triggers that will sort this out automatically should be trivial. That way you'll take care of the count at runtime instead waste I/O and CPU to constantly traverse the data set.

Comment: I like getting the query optimised with indexes as much as possible before increasing resources.. but that may be his only option here. Like the idea of a summary table, super super fast.

Comment: Indexes can't help here. They are not a magic pill that makes everything fast just like that. It's a simple data structure and in this case having an index on `deleted` doesn't help at all. The original query as it is cannot be optimized further using indexes at all. The only available optimization would be dropping the index on `deleted`, which would just free up some storage space. Performance would be the same. The real answer is increasing the resources (default value of innodb_buffer_pool is 8 MB which is way too low) or creating a table to look up counter number.

Comment: Indexes absolutely can help here! The indexes described in my answer cover all the information required by the query so can satisfy the count(*) without the engine having to go into the row to check the entity deleted value.. which will save a lot of memory if entity has lots of columns. Increasing memory size is great but you can only do it once, and it is expensive to keep upgrading the server, so you want your queries as fast as possible. That's why I like the summary table.. solutions that are portable.

Comment: Also if you look at his explain it looks like the optimiser is using the index on deleted over the primary key for entity, which is cray! I'd be wanting to fix that first.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
SELECT count(*) AS count 
  FROM area 
  JOIN entity
    ON entity.id = area.id
   AND entity.deleted = 0 
  JOIN areacust 
    ON areacust.id = area.id
```

I like to include conditions in JOINs where possible and keep the table I'm JOINing on the left of the equals in these conditions.

Also the `WHERE area.id > 0` was strange.. most foreign_keys start at 1 due to auto_increment ids in other tables so this will include all rows. I have deleted this condition.

From the look of your explain, you don't really want the top row to be using `entity_deleted_idx`. You may get more joy with a composite index on `(id, deleted)` for `entity`

These are the indexes i'd have for this query:

- `area` - (id) This is probably the PRIMARY already
- `areacust` - (id) This is probably the PRIMARY already
- `entity` - (id, deleted) This should be added and used.

**UPDATE**

Remove all unsused indexes from the table `entity` except for the PRIMARY and the composite index.

If that doesn't work run:

```
SELECT count(*) AS count 
  FROM area 
  JOIN entity USE INDEX (**composite_index_name**)
    ON entity.id = area.id
   AND entity.deleted = 0 
  JOIN areacust 
    ON areacust.id = area.id
```

Comment: taking same amount of time even more.

Comment: @RahulTailwal Fair enough.. did you try the composite index on (id,deleted)?

Comment: Most optimizers will generate identical plans for this and the original query.  These are semantically identical, so...

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Yes that may be true, but it is way easier to see potential indexes and speed ups with this query, hence my concluding paragraphs.

Comment: @Arth composite index increased the number of rows in explain

Comment: @RahulTailwal Did it now! Did it speed up the query? Or could you post the new explain?

Comment: @RahulTailwal Have you got any explanation for the weird `WHERE area.id > 0`, if not remove that.

Comment: @Arth I have already tried to remove area.id > 0 but did not change anything.

Comment: @RahulTailwal Good, then remove it completely.. it isn't helping. Could you post the new explain after adding the (id, deleted) index.

Comment: @Arth added in the question

Comment: The reason why this takes time is because your database is HDD bound. It simply uses up hard disk I/O because it can't fit the working data set into memory. Culprit is always `innodb_buffer_pool` value, if you use InnoDB (which you should). Increase that number to  at least 70% of the memory of your server (yes, 70%, you want to have as much data as possible in the memory because that's how you get speed).